# Can Delphi insert Excel 2007/2010 table

Tags: delphi, vba, delphi-xe2, excel-2010

I have a Delphi XE2 Application that dumps out a large amount of data to Excel.

As we user Excel 2010 the users have asked whether it is possible for that data to be formatted as a **Table** i.e. with the built-in filters and search tools in the header row

Looking at the VBA it should be reasonably simple

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A1:$Z$999"), , xlYes).Name = "fee"
```

1) I know the range to be converted

2) Both **TExcelApplication** and **TExcelWorkbook** list **ActiveSheet** as an available Property

Here's the problem

3) Neither of these then list **ListObjects** as available.

I'm assuming that this is because Delphi only has support for Excel 2000 or Excel 2003 nativly.  So is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this is because Delphi only has support for Excel 2000 or Excel 2003 natively

1) Delphi has no support for any Excel natively. It is all done with hands-tuned OCX import, and you can make your own import any time you need it!

Delphi Menu: Component / Import COmpionent / Type Library / excel.exe

2) but if you talk about Delphi XE2 it containsthat hand-tuned `c:\RAD Studio\9.0\OCX\Servers\pas2010\Excel2010.pas` for you

And thus Delphi has 3 design-time packages for you:

- c:\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\dcloffice`2010`160.bpl
- c:\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\dcloffice`2K`160.bpl
- c:\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\dcloffice`xp`160.bpl

Comment: Thanks for that.  Why the heck is the 2010 bpl included but not installed?  I'd assumed that the support been frozen!

Comment: The ListObjects.Add in dclOffice2010 seems to require a couple more parameters than the VBA version.  It needs (Source Type, Source, LinkSource, ObjectHasHeaders, Destination, TableStyleName).  I'm assuming that Destination is the only truly new one.  Any ideas?

Comment: Because you need compatibility! If you make new release and suddenly half of you customers can no more work with their version of MS Office - that would hurt you.
You need new features - you explicitly update the library and reduce compatibility. If you do not - you just leave status quo

Comment: No ideas except for reading VBA help in Office 2010. Usually most ofparameters can be filled with default stub values like nil or CURRENT_LOCALE or such

Comment: Found what I needed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823155(v=office.14).aspx. Mostly Emptyparams

Answer (score 2):

I think that is because ActiveSheet is exposed as an IDispatch. You can typecast it first:

```
var
  w: ExcelWorksheet;
begin
  w := ExcelApplication1{....}.ActiveSheet as ExcelWorksheet;
  w.ListObjects.DoAsYouWish;
```

If this is indeed a new feature that is not available at all, ou can import a newer type library. You may want to uninstall the package that contains your current TExcelApplication object first. After that:

- Go to `Component` -> `Import Component...`
- Choose `Importy a Type Library and click Next
- Choose the right type library, which I think is named `Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library`.
- Choose the palette page you want to install the component on, or type a new one, like Office 2010
- Check the box `Generate component wrapper`, which will give you a TExcelApplication component.
- Click Next
- Choose Install into New Package and click Next
- Choose a file name and type the package name (Office 2010).
- Click Finish

You will now have a new unit, but in this one (I just followed these steps), ActiveSheet is still an IDispatch, so you will still need the typecast I posted at first.

Comment: XE2 has Office 2010 support out of the box ;-)

Comment: It probably is new feature, `ListObjects` is missing from `ExcelXP.pas` and `Excel2000.pas`

Comment: as @Arioch'The mentions below there is an Office2010.bpl shipped with XE2 - it's just not installed into the package list!